# How to delete QGraphicsItem properly?

Tags: qt

What I should to do to delete QGraphicsItem?

To remove item from the scene I use

```
 QGraphicsScene::removeItem(QGraphicsItem * item);
```

From the docs for this method:

> i.e., QGraphicsScene will no longer delete item when destroyed

So I see only one way:

```
delete item;
```

But may be another? For example for QWidget is able to set attribute

```
setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose );
```

That causes to deleting of the object. May be there is something similar for QGraphicsItem?

Comment: Item is as base class for all items in QGraphics Scene. As it is not derived from a QObject or a QWidget, I believe that the correct way of deleting it (after removing it from a scene) is just to call `delete item;`

Comment: `item->deleteLater()`

Comment: @ratchetfreak [`deleteLater`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) is `QObject`'s method. `QGraphicsItem` doesn't inherit `QObject` so that can't be used.

Comment: @thuga that is always confusing with Qt :(

Comment: None of the Item-like things do, which makes it annoying if you need to add signals and slots - you have to derive from both. Not too nice.

Comment: @martin_pr Or you can use [`QGraphicsObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html#details).

Comment: @thuga Which does exactly that :)

Comment: @ratchetfreak - there is nothing confusing about this, `deleteLater()` is intended to safely delete objects, which are connected to event loops, so that deletion occurs after all events are processed. If there is no event loop there is no need to use `deleteLater()` nor is it possible absent the event loop, so you just `delete`.

Comment: @martin_pr Yes, but you'll be only deriving from one class :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`QGraphicsItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html) is a base class of all graphics items usable inside `QGraphicsScene`, and, as most "item-like" objects in Qt, is not derived from `QWidget` or `QObject`. Moreover, they can only be parented to another `QGraphicsItem` (apart from being owned by `QGraphicsScene`.

After removing an item from a scene, unless it is parented to another `QGraphicsItem`, Qt expects the programmer to delete it manually by calling `delete item;` explicitly (or to use a smart pointer to manage the lifetime of the item after it was removed).

Comment: You don't _have_ to call `delete` explicitly if you put it in a smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr` or any of Qt's smart pointer classes.

Comment: Yup, fair enough, I will amend the answer to take this into account.

Comment: @rubenvb - I'd say explicitly using a smart pointer just to tie the lifetime of a graphics item to a function scope is actually more effort than simply deleting it manually. Unless you can present an example where the smart pointer can manage the graphics item for its entire lifetime, not just for the sake of avoiding manual deletion in the very end of it.

Comment: @ddriver who said anything about function scope? The `QGraphicsItem` will be owned by _something_, right? A vector of all `QGraphicsItem`s will suffice, and makes it explicit who owns what, because clearly, `QGraphicsScene` won't clean up after itself...

Comment: @rubenvb However, for as long as the item is owned by a scene (or another item), it will get cleaned up, so a vector of `QGraphicsItem`s attempting to manage them during their entire lifetime will actually cause a double deletion. I think we are getting a bit academical here :)

Comment: @rubenvb - so you suggest it is efficient to store pointers to each and every item just to avoid calling delete? That's entirely redundant, considering the scene/item hierarchy already implements an "ownership" model, albeit not a lifetime managing one. And god forbid you have a bug and you remove items from the smart pointer vector that are still in the scene - bad boom boom. And it is the same effort to remove the pointer from the vector as it is to delete manually... Are you one of those "new/delete is harmful and wrong and should not be used" evangelists?

Comment: @martin_pr - nope it won't, graphics items do not use smart pointers for their parent/child properties.

Comment: @ddriver They don't, but they [do delete all their children](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#dtor.QGraphicsItem) on destruction.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, my bad. MY BAD. I'd argue `removeItem` should return the pointer so you can immediately wrap it up (or `delete` it), or at least put it somewhere safe. Alas, Qt's API conflicts with modern C++ more and more... But yes, I'm a "don't use `new`/`delete` evangelist" because, well, exception safety and all.

Comment: Well, +1 more reasons to not use smart pointers. I personally never really delete graphics items, just move "deleted" items to an undo queue, which itself decides when a history step needs to be flushed out of existence.

Comment: @rubenvb - well, you cannot redo entire frameworks for every new whimsical new feature of a language. And nobody said you should use smart pointers for each and every dynamic allocation, I'd say most of the time it is entirely needles, especially with a framework such as Qt, which has its long standing and easy to use programming idioms. No need to become fanatical over the use of "recommended good practices" especially when they don't fit in an already established usage paradigm. It becomes backward and undermines the very idea of those new features.

Comment: @rubenvb I'd even argue that Qt's API conflicts with programmer's sanity more and more :) And yes, I fully agree, but that is simply not the Qt way :)

Comment: @ddriver it is impossible to guarantee exception safety in a Qt program just because of its idioms. There are many situations in which several calls to new follow each other before some of the allocated objects are reparented.

Comment: @martin_pr "I'd even argue that Qt's API conflicts with programmer's sanity more and more" - you sound like one of those people who hasn't used Qt back in the days it was tremendously more insane to program in C++ without Qt's aids. Qt made C++ easy and elegant, and just because those did not match what the STD committee came up with afterwards, doesn't mean it is insane. As bad as some aspects of Qt's design philosophy might be, I'd say the STD committee and its decisions in evolving C++ are actually more insane.

Comment: @rubenvb - and yet there is no other framework that can compete with Qt. AS bad as some aspects of Qt might be, it is the best (or least bad) thing we have ;)

Comment: @ddriver I dont want to be involved in a flame war, but let me post one last response - you are right that back in those days, Qt was a decently designed library. I am not questioning that. However, it failed to evolve with the rest of the world, and now its concepts are obsolete. The fact that it has been used for many projects does not negate that. rubenvb's exception safety comment is actually something that forces Qt programmers to completely firewall Qt code from all the rest of modern C++ code. Modern C++ is powerful, clean and its design peer reviewed - it doesnt get better than that.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! Can you please expand it to include case when `QGraphicsScene` is deleted while `QGraphicsItem` is attached to it. Does item get deleted then?

Comment: @EdinM According to the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem), the `QGraphicsScene` takes ownership of any item added to it. So yes, items still attached to the scene will get deleted when the scene is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue lasting for long time today and there are open bugs also.

But it seems to have a workaround, which I could find it useful and after hours of debugging and reading and investigations I have found it here:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/71316/qgraphicsscenefinditembsptreevisitor-visit-crashes-due-to-an-obsolete-paintevent-after-qgraphicsscene-removeitem/17

Some other tips and tricks regarding Graphics Scene here: https://tech-artists.org/t/qt-properly-removing-qgraphicitems/3063/6